# gzip - is there a risk to lose files during compression if process dead?

Tags: gnu-screen, compression, gzip, data

Is there a risk of losing files during compression if process dies? I'm gzipping big files using wildcard, but accidentally running it without `screen` or `nohup`. Is there a risk to lose source files if I cancel gzip compression during creating archive? Gzip version:

```
gzip 1.3.5
(2002-09-30)
```

Please let me know, I'm afraid of loosing data.

Comment: to the best that I know, gzip doesn't delete the original file before it successfully finishes the compression. So, other than a fluke instance, you will not lose your original file(s)

Comment: it sounds good, the only thing I'm not sure regarding this particular version.

Comment: @user3417815 This behaviour (delete only after successful compression, was already in `gzip`'s predecessor `compress`), but if you don't trust it for your gzip version you can check it out: open a new terminal, make a copy of large enough file, start `gzip` and Ctrl-C the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is no chance of losing during compression. Only when the file is complete processed is the source deleted (that is, if you don't specify `-k` or `--keep`, in which case the source is not deleted at all).